# What Does Cached Data Include?

Tags: samsung, cache

I have 6.1 gb of cached data on my phone and I would like to clear it, but I'm not sure what is "cached data."  Would this reset the games I have on my phone?  Other things?

What does cached data include?

Comment: I am the poster of this question, and I just registered to this site.  How do I like this question to my account?  Also, Samsung Galaxy S 5 needs a tag.

Comment: Well, check this article for detailed information ; http://www.howtogeek.com/school/basic-android-guide/lesson5/all/

Answer (score 1):

CACHED DATA could contain :

- Precompiled applications to make them faster
- Saved databases
- Downloaded images/webpages from your web browser
- Data to be copied by some apps
- Thumbnails (light preview of images for faster rendering)

You can clean it whenever you want. Since you have 6.1GB I bet it comes from your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Cached data is basically temporary storage for your apps. You can clear it all and nothing will happen. In fact you should be clearing it regularly.

Caching is basically storing already processed information so it doesn't have to be processed again and can just be lifted from the cache when needed. This includes things like Gallery thumbnails, the last opened sites in your browser, etc.

If you want more details just Google caching in android. But to answer your question yes you can clear your cached data with no effect on your apps and games.

Answer (score 0):

What is Cached Data

The Cached data is nothing but files, images, scripts and other media files stored on your devices by the website or app. Data is stored on your devices in a reserved space, so the next time when you are visiting the app or website, information is already available. It makes the process faster as it does not require to load all the files again.

Reference: [mobipicker.com](https://www.mobipicker.com/what-is-cached-data/)